# Warp/Bend Objects?

Tags: objects

I have made these steps and I'd like to fit them better to the curved shape of the structure they are attached to by bending them to a curve. Is there a tool that would allow me to do this in one go? How would one go about doing this?

[image]

Comment: If you already know the way by using curve, you may also consider using Lattice + Proportional Editing.

Answer (score 3):

I would Select the *Edge* I want the stairs to be,

[image]

Then I would duplicate the edge and convert it into a curve by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> - 'Curve from Mesh/Text',

[image]

and Finally I would give the stairs Curve Modifier, and as an object to deform with I would select my Curve.

*don't forget to subdivide the stairs*
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't work for me. Perhaps I am missing something you didn't mention.  Even when I create a new mesh plane and attempt to do this, the curve modifier doesn't do anything except move my object to a point a mile away from where it was. What am I missing here?

Comment: Select the object and move it where you want it to be, it will adjust by itself